# Starting with KDE Frameworks 5 and Qt Creator

Tags: linux, qt, qt-creator, kde-plasma

I've installed fresh QtCreator and Qt 5.8 to my system.
As I understand there are 2 Qt toolchains right now on my PC: One in `~/Qt/5.8` (default path) and one is in `usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin` where KDE stores it for own purposes. The one in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin` is version 5.7.
Ok, If I create a dummy project in Qt Creator then it'll allow me to choose only Qt 5.8 Kit. And if I do so I'll get `Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: KF5DBusAddons` on any KDE Frameworks module I want to link.
(I'm linking them by `QT += KF5DBusAddons` in .pro file)
It seems that's because Qt 5.8 don't know about KDE modules in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/modules/` because it looks into `~/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/mkspecs/modules/` instead. And there are no KDE modules. They are not suggested as an option in Qt Online Installer tool.

Fine, so I need either add a Qt5.7 from `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` or install KDE Frameworks 5 on top of Qt 5.8. I've tried the first one and run into configuration problems. It still cann't see modules in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`.

My question is: Is there a working tutorial on how to start with KDE Framework and Qt Creator. Can I stick with qmake toolchain and not cmake files? Or working explanation on how to add System Qt libraries as a Kit into QtCreator?

P.S. I'm trying to use `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++-64/qmake.conf` And my qmake result command line is `qmake /home/user1/dev/kdbustest/kdbustest.pro -spec /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++-64/ CONFIG+=debug && /usr/bin/make qmake_all`

Comment: Would be nice which distro you are using. Also I really doubt that in most of the distros (unless using Arch or some other distro that offers pre-build packages for the latest versions) they use even 5.7 or 5.6 for the respective KDE dev ones. If you want to develop KDE-based application I would suggest to stick with the default packages that your package manager offers and that are also used by your distro. Otherwise you are in for nasty errors and compatibility issues.

Comment: I've pulled Kubuntu 17.04 which is still is beta I think but will be released in a month. It has 5.7 onboard by default. So they are default packages.

Comment: So you have a 5.7 and also your own 5.8 at the same time? Does the `qt-chooser` work with selecting which version you want to use by default? Also if you want to use 5.8 with packages build with 5.7 you will likely run into many problems (as I've mentioned in the previous comment) especially when it comes to QML.

Comment: `qtchooser -print-env` says it's switched to 5.7 by default `QTLIBDIR="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu"` I didn't touch it. And I'm fine with 5.7 as apparently only it has KDE Frameworks modules. I don't want to use 5,8 with 5,7 packages. I want make my QtCreator 4.2 use 5.7 toolkit. 5.8 is the kit that goes throw online installer. I could disable it and get QtCreator only. But that change nothing as the problem is in making it work with default Qt, The 5.8 which is downloaded online attaches to QtCreator automatically like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt creator has its own configuration for qt versions used in builds.

the config is in `tools > options > build and run > Kits`

Make sure the kit you have selected (e.g. Desktop) has the correct Qt version set.

If the qt version you want isn't in the dropdown, you can add it in the Qt Versions tab.

Also check you have the right kit selected to build your project (see the build configuration button - above the run/green play button)

The mkspec should be automatically set to use the system qt version and modules, but you can make sure by setting Qt mkspec (in `tools > options > build and run > Kits`) to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++-64/`

After all this, you can verify the correct command is being run by looking at the compile compile output pane when running `build > Run qmake`.

Comment: Hm, looks like i did something wrong yesterday. Just retried it with a newly created KIt today and everything works. And KDE Frameworks modules are visible for qmkae. Thanks!