# Using KDE frameworks and Qt Creator installed without apt

Tags: linux, qt, ubuntu, kde-plasma

A similar question has already been asked here [Starting with KDE Frameworks 5 and Qt Creator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42879952/starting-with-kde-frameworks-5-and-qt-creator). However, the answer still hasn't clarified my doubts. So here is the problem: on Linux (Ubuntu) there are two ways to install Qt, first is to use `apt` (`sudo apt install qt5-default`) and the other one is to download Qt from the official website. Now when you install using the first way Qt is installed by defualt `/usr/lib` and the second way in the home folder (or in `/opt` if you ran the installed with administrator privileges). 
Now I would like to integrate KDE Frameworks 5 in my project so on the official [website](https://techbase.kde.org/KDE_Frameworks) it is suggested to use:

`sudo apt install framework`

And then you can just include that in your project by `QT += framework`. The problem is I installed Qt using the second way (downloading from the website) and as a result Qt Creator always return `Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: framework`. This I believe is because Qt doesn't seem to be aware of the fact that the modules are in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/modules/` instead it probably looks for them somewhere else.
How do I solve this problem with a permanent solution? I cannot install Qt using `apt` because I would like to use the latest version which usually in not immediately available in the default repositories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after a looking a lot, a solution has been suggested here https://forum.qt.io/topic/104861/how-to-use-kde-frameworks-with-qt-creator/8
Essentially Qt, if not installed through the system's repositories, is unable to find the KF5 modules. In order to fix this you can add a QMAKEPATH environment build variable to your project that tells Qt where it should look for the module, in my case this was in

> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5